# Secure super user account within octopus deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

I have been tasked with developing a service that takes requests for admin access to a windows server, receives approval from management, grants access, and then automatically revokes access after an hour.

I am required to do all deployments through Octopus Deploy.

I cannot store the super user password within the service, since all developers have read access to our SVN.

I was planning on storing the password within a secure variable in Octopus Deploy, but then realized that anyone with modification permissions on the project could add a powershell script to send themselves the variable values.

Is there any way to secure a variable within Octopus Deploy that can be used to install a windows service with super user access, but cannot be retrieved by any means?

Comment: Although it makes it more of a pain, perhaps you could set up a separate Octopus Deploy project that only installs the super user password in the service, and then restrict access to that separate Octopus Deploy project to yourself only.

Answer (score 1):

How I have this setup uses a combination of roles and environments to limit access to sensitive variables such as prod passwords.

You need two roles:

1) is a project editor role that allows developers to do everything but only for Dev/UAT environments. This allows them to get everything ready and tested without access to the prod environment.

2) a production editor role which only a few people have access to. Production password variables are scoped to the Prod environment so developers can't access them.

Comment: this is the correct way to do it.  Also take  into account when you do this that you will most likey need to give the developers access to unscoped variables which is a separate permission and can affect production.  But your production SECRET  can be scoped to only production and thus limited.